# vue-router: how to detect dead links?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

When using vue-router, how can I find dead links? If it's not SPA, you can find such dead links by using, for example, [this](https://www.deadlinkchecker.com/) or any similar crawler. However, SPA, or vue-router specifically in my case, does not return 404 and thus the dead link cannot be detected.

vue-router actually complains about missing route if you use the form `:to="{name: 'routeName'}` but it only happens when the component is created (visited), which means that you have to actually visit the route where you have the links to be checked.

Is there any way to search dead links throughout a website using vue-router?